# SSIS-IR "There is no active worker agent."

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory

I have a SSIS-IR running in data factory that is misbehaving!

I have a SSIS project that I have added a package that processes a file and if this job fails due to misconfigured file path or other file related issue I get an error in the SSIDB as per the image. "Unexpected Termination"
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHD1N.png)

Any subsequent job or project deployment will throw the error "There is no active worker agent."

The agent is started in Data Factory and is showing as available so I'm at a bit of a loss. Restarting solves the issue but it takes circa 30 minutes to bounce the integration runtime so is a real PITA when trying to solve my file problem.

Comment: 13 Nov 2018 - this was an issue from about 13:30AEST to 14:30 AEST

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue that may cause the "There is no active worker agent" error in SSIS Integration Runtime now and we are actively working on the fix. Could you try to set you Logging Level to None when executing the package and see whether it solves the problem? Thanks.

Best regards,
Rodge

Comment: I resolved in the end by setting multiple nodes on the IR and letting them fail 1 by 1 until I sorted the issues.